# Problema con metodo psh

Tags: javascript, android, angular, firebase, ionic

Estoy creando una app para un lavado de carros y necesito agregar la marca, modelo y matrícula del vehículo.

Estoy haciendo la app en ionic con angular y estoy utilizando firebase realtime como base de datos.

Este es mi servicio donde se encuentra el CRUD realizado.

Aquí el código.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import {Client} from '../share/Client'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AppointmentService {

  bookingListRef: AngularFireList <any>;
  bookingRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }
  // Create
  createBooking(apt: Client) {
    return this.bookingListRef.push({
      marca: apt.marca,
      modelo: apt.modelo,
      matricula: apt.Matricula,

    })
  }
  // Get Single
  getBooking(id: string) {
    this.bookingRef = this.db.object('/client/' + id);
    return this.bookingRef;
  }
  // Get List
  getBookingList() {
    this.bookingListRef = this.db.list('/client');
    return this.bookingListRef;
  }
  // Update
  updateBooking(id, apt: Client) {
    return this.bookingRef.update({
      marca: apt.marca,
      modelo: apt.modelo,
      matricula: apt.Matricula,

    })
  }
   // Delete
   deleteBooking(id: string) {
    this.bookingRef = this.db.object('/client/' + id);
    this.bookingRef.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: intenta con bookingListRef: AngularFireList <any> = [];

Comment: no funciona haciendolo de esa manera